# How to make header files can be include via Library name?

Tags: c++, cmake, include, clion

I'm trying to make a cross-platforms crypto library in C++ at https://github.com/haithngn/cryptor something like https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2

The Structure is:

[image]

Can I make any header files can be include in the statements like this:

```
#include <Cryptor/MD5Encryptor.h>
```

I can include these header directly from absolutely file path

```
../core/CryptorCore.h
```

But these format will make the source code cannot build succeed in an XCode Project.

I tried to simulate the MailCore2 but that's very difficult.

Hope you can suggest me any solution or do a favor PR on my Repository.

Thanks,

Comment: Why can't you just change your development directory structure to match the deployment directory structure?

Comment: The source code will not be match with Objective-C/Swift syntax when we port to Apple platform framework

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a proper hierarchy. First, no, you can't have

```
#include <Cryptor/MD5Encryptor.h>
```

with your current setup, not while building the library, and not without flattening the hierarchy when installing your files (which CMake can do).

What you can do is:

```
#include <Cryptor/core/abstract/MD5Encryptor.h>
```

if you add your project inside a `Cryptor` folder instead of being at the root of your project.
I would advise you to create a `Cryptor.cmake` file that would allow people to pick up your library once installed, so that they don't have to know where the library includes are or what the libraries name is.

Comment: Could you please check this Repository https://github.com/MailCore/mailcore2?
Their header files can be include via <MailCore/....h> Can we do that ?

If I have to use these format <Cryptor/core/abstract... that could not be build in any XCode project.

Comment: Note that the source hierarchy is not necessarily the same as the install hierarchy.

Comment: They have done something intermediate (and dirty) with this: `file(COPY
  ${public_headers}

  DESTINATION
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include/MailCore"
)`. I don't like that approach of copying files and having them twice, one of them not being update when the first one is changed + all the issues with relative includes.

Comment: @YSC indeed, you can change it, but it's probably better to have consistency as well.

Comment: I agree; but it might be the solution OP is looking for ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Matthieu Brucher

Answer (score 0):

It should not be necessary to point to every single header file. Just add all directories containing these header files with `include_directories(PATH_TO_HEADERS)`.

For the include of the header file src/core/CryptorCore.h with

```
#include "CryptorCore.h"
```

you have to point to

```
include_directories(${PROJECT_DIR}/core/)
```